# Can't see cycles render devices

Tags: cycles-render-engine, customization

I can't see cycles render devices in system tab[image]. I use 2.93.6.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Cycles is an addon that it’s possible to accidentally disable. Edit preferences. Go to addins and search for cycles. Make sure it’s enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have always been active in cycles render but I can't see in the system tab. That makes me confused. I have a Radeon Pro Vega display card. Would it make this problem?